# Django add user to group error "is not a valid UUID"

Tags: django

Sorry for my english. I want add user to group, but i have custom `User` whith id

`id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)`

then i try add user to custom group:

```
user = User.objects.filter(email=request.user.email)
        my_group = Group.objects.get(name='test_group')
        my_group.user_set.add(user)
```

but have eroor

```
["'<QuerySet [<User: nesalexy@gmail.com>]>' is not a valid UUID."]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter` return queryset - list of objects, but you need to pass to `add` single object, so instead of filter use `get`:

```
user = User.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
my_group = Group.objects.get(name='test_group')       
my_group.user_set.add(user)
```